# Can't update software with Update Manager due to telepathy-butterfly

Tags: update-manager

When I try to update my Ubuntu 11.10 I get this message after downloading everything "The installation or removal of a software package failed.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'telepathy-butterfly' is missing final newline
Error in function: "
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install any packages due to unrecoverable fatal error /var/lib/dpkg/diversions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100046/unable-to-install-any-packages-due-to-unrecoverable-fatal-error-var-lib-dpkg-di)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  open a Terminal and try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And then afterwards, if successful, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If these don't work, consider removing the offending package

```
sudo apt-get remove telepathy-butterfly
```

and if you wish, try to reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install telepathy-butterfly
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now, I made my 16.04 version CD.  How can I use it to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my dual booting system alongside Windows 10 with out any damage. Please give the step-by-step procedure to do so. The existing version15.10 is no more useful to me. Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your instruction fetched:  prasad@prasad-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ sudo apt-get remove telepathy-butterfly
[sudo] password for prasad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package telepathy-butterfly