# bad downloaded packages? linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae' is missing final newline

Tags: upgrade, apt, package-management

I'm having some trouble updating my software. It seems like the new packages have been downloaded but one package is giving me some trouble

This is the output I get when I try to upgrade my software packages:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  activity-log-manager-common activity-log-manager-control-center apport
  apport-gtk apt-transport-https apt-utils bind9-host brasero brasero-cdrkit
  brasero-common busybox-static checkbox checkbox-qt compiz compiz-core
  compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default cups-pk-helper deja-dup dhcp3-server
  dkms dnsutils duplicity ffmpeg firefox firefox-globalmenu
  firefox-gnome-support firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer
  fonts-opensymbol gdb gimp gimp-data gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-games-data gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-sudoku gnome-themes-standard gnomine grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin
  grub2-common gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gwibber gwibber-service
  gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-7-jre-cacao
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm indicator-messages indicator-status-provider-mc5
  jockey-common jockey-gtk jupiter libbind9-80 libbrasero-media3-1
  libdecoration0 libdns81 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libgimp2.0
  libglu1-mesa libgnome-control-center1 libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2
  libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblwres80 libnautilus-extension1a libnm-glib-vpn1
  liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libpq5 libpurple-bin
  libpurple0 libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-help-en-us
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libtelepathy-glib0
  libunity-core-5.0-5 libupnp3 libvlc5 libvlccore5 light-themes linux-libc-dev
  mahjongg make man-db mtp-tools nautilus nautilus-data openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre
  openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib openssl overlay-scrollbar
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-apport python-keyring python-libproxy python-libxml2
  python-problem-report python-ubuntu-sso-client seahorse skype skype-bin
  software-center synaptic thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us
  transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-standard unattended-upgrades
  unity unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-services vino
  vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse xorg xserver-xorg
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xul-ext-ubufox
160 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/229 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 90%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
```

The problem first showed up trying to upgrade through Ubuntu update manager which recommends trying the -f option from the command line.

Do I need to somehow purge my downloaded but uninstalled packages? Seems like the Linux image file may be bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install any packages due to unrecoverable fatal error /var/lib/dpkg/diversions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100046/unable-to-install-any-packages-due-to-unrecoverable-fatal-error-var-lib-dpkg-di)

Answer (score 4):

You have scrambled the meta information in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.
That doesn't sound good.

**Check that /var/ isn't filled up by inspecting the output of `df`.**

A way to recover from this situation is to remove the problematic file and reinstall the package afterwards.

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
mv -f linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae.* /tmp/ 
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic-pae.deb
```

With a little bit of luck it was the only scrambled package and you can retry the `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that seemed to do it. Your first two commands worked but the last one I couldn't get to work but I managed to do the same thing from synaptic. Now all packages are up to date.

Comment: @brian If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.