# apt-get install fails due to empty /var/lib/dpkg/diversions

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

I've got a freshly installed trusty installation, where I have so far done the following:

1. Installed
2. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (and ran the update)

After a reboot (though I'm unsure of when exactly it broke, I've rebooted a few times now since then), now I'm unable to install anything via apt. Attempting to install gives:

```
mitch@corundum:/media$ sudo apt-get install htop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  htop
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/68.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 188 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Use of uninitialized value $value in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 65, <__ANONIO__> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $item in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 85, <__ANONIO__> chunk 1.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 fgets gave an empty string from `/var/lib/dpkg/diversions'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I've searched for the penultimate line and found a few links, but none of them helped.

For example, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100046/unable-to-install-any-packages-due-to-unrecoverable-fatal-error-var-lib-dpkg-di) question runs a python script as the most upvoted answer - tried that, but it's no good.

Both the files at `/var/lib/dpkg/diversions` and `/var/lib/dpkg/diversions-old` are empty - thus, replacing the current with the old doesn't do anything.

How do I get this to install?

Answer (score 0):

You might be affected by a reported [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/13130) in `debconf`. If you read the comments there one user was able to fix this by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf
```

See if the same works for you.